# Python script fails at this line

Tags: python, file, pycharm, python-os

I have a python script that fails at a specific line of code. I wrote it on Sublime text and had no errors. This is on Python 3.8 & 3.7.

```
import os
import glob
import time
```

`<lines 4-28 of script are omitted>`

```
list_of_files = glob.glob('Y:\\foldername\\foldername\\Reports\\*.csv')
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
create_time = os.path.getctime(latest_file)
```

When I run this script in PyCharm it fails with the following error confirming its that an issue with this specific line of code `latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)`

Here is the error in PyCharm

```
 line 30, in <module>
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime) ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

If I remove that one line the script runs fine in Windows Task Scheduler and in IDLE and everywhere. I am going to probably just find another way to get the latest file in the specified folder.

Can you guys help me figure out why the script fails? Does the Value error mean I cannot give any parameters to max()? Or point me in the right direction to fix it. Im fairly new to python so this is a learning opportunity!

Comment: The error seems pretty clear. `list_of_files` is an empty list (i.e. `[]`).

Comment: The message likely means that `latest_file` is empty - i.e. it did not find your file

Comment: Well there you go, I added print(lists_of_files) and its an empty list! However I go to the path and its full of CSV files.

Comment: it looks like my list was empty because I have the wrong drive letter, then the script was not running because until I used the UNC path with forward slash instead of backslash so.. //fileserver/share$/folder/folder/*.csv and now my script runs great!